# Connecting a Dialog with Luis in Microsoft BotFramework v4 node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Previously I have worked a lot with the BotFramework V3 in node.js, however BotFramework V4 is very different and it seems that I cannot get it right.

I am struggling for days now with the start of a dialog after a Luis intent is recognized.

I receive the following error:

> `[onTurnError]: TypeError: context.beginDialog is not a function`

I have checked similar issues at Stackoverflow but there is no clear answer yet.

See an example of my bot below:

```
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');
const { LuisRecognizer } = require('botbuilder-ai');

const WelcomeCard = require('./resources/welcomeCard.json');
const { CardFactory, ActionTypes, ActivityTypes } = require('botbuilder-core');

const {DatavisualisatieDialog} = require('./Dialogs/DatavisualisatieDialog');


class TestBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(luisRecognizer) {
        super('TestBot');

        this.luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {

            const luisResult = await this.luisRecognizer.executeLuisQuery(context);

            switch (LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult)) {

            case 'Datavisualisatie': {

                await context.beginDialog(DatavisualisatieDialog);
            }

                break;

            default:
            // Catch all for unhandled intents
            const didntUnderstandMessageText = `text`;
            await context.sendActivity(didntUnderstandMessageText, didntUnderstandMessageText);

            }
        });

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; ++cnt) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    // activation of the welcomecard 
                    const welcomeCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(WelcomeCard);
                    await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [welcomeCard] });
                    await context.sendActivity('text');
                }
            }
            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}

module.exports.TestBot = TestBot;
```

Answer (score 0):

`beginDialog` exists on `DialogContext`, but not `TurnContext`. You'd use `Dialog.run(context, dialogState)` to start a new dialog from `ActivityHandler.onMessage`.

So you need to instantiate your `DatavisualisatieDialog`, then call `run` from within `onMessage`.

This sample has a full e2e sample of it working: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/19.custom-dialogs/bots/dialogBot.js#L24-L32

(P.S. if you're using VS Code, you can add `// @ts-check` to the top of your JS files and get red squiggles for type errors, which it would probably catch here.)